# Need LED lighting suggestions for a hobby spray booth

Tags: lighting, led

I am writing the plans to build a small indoor hobby spray booth largely used for aerosol acrylics and acrylic airbrush but possibly some aerosol enamels at times.  I am using a range hood which includes weak (2x 25w) incandescent bulbs.  I want to install LEDs inside of the spray booth; fluorescents can be an explosion hazard for some aerosol paints.  I would like to get roughly the same lighting as 2x 100w Reveal light bulbs, or brighter if possible.  I have been looking at various cabinet LED solutions but I am not sure if they will be bright enough.

I will be installing flexible arm LED lights on the outside of the booth for looking in so the LEDs just need to illuminate from the top and back of the target.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear. There's no specific question posed. OP hasn't been here in five years.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [good document](http://www.brillianz.co.uk/data/documents/Lumen.pdf) that briefly explains how LEDs are rated vs other lights like flourescent and incandescent. And here's a [website](http://www.led-tape.com/led-strips/high-single-colour) which has high powered LED strips.  You'll have to be the judge as to whether they provide the amount of light you're looking for since LEDs concentrate the light on an area, whereas incandescent shoots it out in a sphere.

Comment: Great information in that document.  I spent a lot of time in the Home Depot lighting aisle and searching for LEDs on Google but it was pretty hard to formulate what, exactly, I was looking for (even after scanning a Wikipedia article on the subject).  Now I have a much better idea.

Comment: Yes, LED strips are the way to go with that.  For 200W equivalent i would say about 20W of strip or a single 5-metre 3528 single color strip.  The LED isn't wasting any energy lighting up the backside of reflectors, and you are positioning the light exactly where you want it, instead of spray-and-pray.   I would cover the LED strips with someting, even just Saran Wrap taped down, so if you get paint on them it's easily fixed.